# Running out of disk space because of wrong partition set up

Tags: linux, software-raid, diskmanagement

Server on Debian Jessie that was set up wrongly without doing the default partitions on install..

Now the server is running out of memory as it is not using the available disk space.

```
Disk Usage:
/dev/md1    ext4       37G   29G    6.0G    83% /
udev        devtmpfs   10M   0      10M     0%  /dev
tmpfs       tmpfs      6.3G  657M   5.7G    11% /run
/dev/md0    ext4       268M  32M    218M    13% /boot
/dev/md2    ext4       410G  71M    389G    1%  /data
```

Server has 3 x 250 GB SSD.
Server for web hosting using ISPconfig 3 control panel.

Any pointers on how or where to find docs to correct this to start using the available disk space over the 3 disks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The partitioning is fine, but data is not being written to the empty data partition.

Just needed to send the data to the empty partition and add a symlink.

```
mkdir /data/www
mv /var/www/* /data/www
rmdir /var/www
ln -s /data/www /var/www
```

To find other large files using disk space using

`du -hsx /*`

So did the same for logs and moved them to the data partition

```
mkdir /data/var_log
mv /var/log/* /data/var_log
rmdir /var/log
ln -s /data/var_log /var/log
```